# Stop Autofac injecting value for a specific property

Tags: asp.net, webforms, autofac

Is there a way to stop Autofac from injecting a value into a property?

I have a property on a WebForms user control which is being set during the init and is getting overwritten by Autofac.  Is there a way to stop autofac from injecting into the property without switching off property injection all together?

EDIT: 
The modules I'm using are....

```
<httpModules>
  <add 
    name="ContainerDisposal" 
    type="Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" />
  <add 
    name="PropertyInjection" 
    type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" />
  <add 
    name="AttributeInjection" 
    type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.AttributedInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" />
</httpModules>
```

I realise I could probably just remove the property injection module and switch it off for all properties.

As per MaDeRkAn's suggestion looking at the code in my particular case I've changed the particular properties I don't want injection on from being public to being an explicit implementation of an interface.

Not an ideal solution I'd have preferred to have Attributes that you can apply to properties or classes to either opt-in or opt-out properties for autofac injection.  Similar to how attributes are used to control the serialization of a class.

Comment: You can just register properties you want or you should write a method like `PropertiesAutowired`. Check this [method](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/36b69bffbdd96cfe8d7a56a62b16f518dd72f590/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/AutowiringPropertyInjector.cs) you should write this kind of method plus you will send types which you don't want to resolve and continue loop if there is match.

Comment: Can you post which modules you're running in your app?